# Cant get text from an EditText object in dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

So from a menu item I want to display a dialog that allows the user to input some text. The dialog works just fine, but when I try to do anything with the EditText object the app shuts down. May have something to do with the layout of the dialog I am using but I am not sure. Below is the method that is called when pressing the corresponding menu item:

```
private void showChangeDownloadURLDialog() {
    mapShouldRefresh = false;

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = MapsActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

    final EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urladdress);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this)
    .setTitle(R.string.map_menu_test)
    .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_url, null))
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.i(TAG, "click ok");
            String mString = mEditText.getEditableText().toString();
            Log.i(TAG, "New URL is: " + mString);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Does nothing
        }
    })
    .create()
    .show();
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try for String mString = mEditText.getText().toString();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code would be:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = MapsActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_url, null);
final EditText mEditText = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.urladdress);
new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this)
    .setTitle(R.string.map_menu_test)
    .setView(content)
//....
```

Comment: get the EditText from the View obtained from the inflator... bingo. Thanks bud

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private void showChangeDownloadURLDialog() {
mapShouldRefresh = false;

// Get the layout inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = MapsActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

final EditText mEditText = new EditText(MapsActivity.this);

new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this)
.setTitle(R.string.map_menu_test)
.setView(mEditText)
.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Log.i(TAG, "click ok");
        String mString = mEditText.getEditableText().toString();
        Log.i(TAG, "New URL is: " + mString);
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Does nothing
    }
})
.create()
.show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this

```
final EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urladdress);
```

is in

```
R.layout.change_url
```

move it under

```
.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_url, null))
```

You are trying to assign the `View` before its `ViewGroup` (`layout`) is inflated